# How to run mongo db as service using non-default dbpath?

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

When i try to start a service I get

```
~$ sudo service mongodb start
mongodb start/running, process 20221
```

but it doesn't really start 
    ~$ sudo service mongodb status
    mongodb stop/waiting

it's probably because my dbpath is NOT default
so how to start a m service using non-default dbpath

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884233/mongodb-service-is-not-starting-up. The answer is `--dbpath` switch or `/etc/mongodb.conf` copnfiguration

Comment: You should also look in /var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log as it should show start-up error messages.

Answer (score 8):

This doesn't really have anything to do with a "service" it's down to the `mongod` (MongoDB's process name) parameters to use a `dbpath` other than `/data/db`

To find out what paramters are available to you can you simplely run ...

`$ mongod --help`

And you'll get a list of *helpful* parameters, there are also extensive docs explaining the various differant parameters you can use when starting up mongod ...

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Starting+and+Stopping+Mongo

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Command+Line+Parameters

A bit from the docs on your issue ...

> ### Starting mongod
>
> Default Data Directory, Default Port To start Mongo in default mode,
>   where data will be stored in the /data/db directory (or c:\data\db on
>   Windows), and listening on port 27017, just type
>
> `$ ./mongod`
>
> **Alternate Data Directory, Default Port**
>
> To specify a directory for Mongo to store files, use the --dbpath
>   option:
>
> `$ ./mongod --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb/`
>
> Note that you must create the directory and set its permissions
>   appropriately ahead of time -- Mongo will not create the directory if
>   it doesn't exist.
>
> **Alternate Port**
>
> You can specify a different port for Mongo to listen on for
>   connections from clients using the --port option
>
> `$ ./mongod --port 12345`
>
> This is useful if you want to run more than one instance of Mongo on a
>   machine (e.g., for running a master-slave pair).
>
> **Running as a Daemon**
>
> Note: these options are only available in MongoDB version 1.1 and
>   later.
>
> This will fork the Mongo server and redirect its output to a logfile. 
>   As with --dbpath, you must create the log path yourself, Mongo will
>   not create parent directories for you.
>
> `$ ./mongod --fork --logpath /var/log/mongodb.log --logappend`

Comment: Well, the question relates to the service, so this answer is a bit off topic. Probaly suggesting to tweak /etc/mongodb.conf would have been better.

Answer (score 6):

You can specify it with config file.

I found explanation here : http://blog.ajduke.in/2013/04/10/install-setup-and-start-mongodb-on-windows/

> ## Using the config file
>
> Instead of specifying command line option, we can specify same with use of file, which i call it here as config file Config file is just normal file, containing the parameters in the key=value form and each is on the every line of file In this, we basically provide path to file (which contains the configurations) as command line option as “-f” or “–config” Following is the snippet for the config file

```
shell > mongod --config I:\Servers\mongodb\config\mongodb.conf
```

And you get a file where you can specify dbpath :

> #This is an example config file for MongoDB
>    #basic
>   dbpath = I:\Servers\mongodb\data
>   port = 27017
>   logpath = I:\Servers\mongodb\logs\mongo.log