# MongoDB running locally but when trying to access remotely it failed

Tags: mongodb

Able to run MongoDB locally but when trying to access remotely it failed. Havent done any firewall setup. What could be the issue? How to do troubleshoot?

Also the MongoDB status show running

```
service mongod status
mongod (pid 25342) is running...
```

But when trying to restart the service it says

```
service mongod restart
Stopping mongod:                                           [  OK  ]
Starting mongod:                                           [FAILED]
```

But still the process is running

**Update**

Tried  mongod --repair here is the update

```
2015-01-10T10:46:33.109-0500 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=29018 port=2                                                                                        7017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=ns4008927.ip-192-99-3.net
2015-01-10T10:46:33.109-0500 [initandlisten] db version v2.6.6
2015-01-10T10:46:33.109-0500 [initandlisten] git version: 608e8bc319627693b04cc7                                                                                        da29ecc300a5f45a1f
2015-01-10T10:46:33.109-0500 [initandlisten] build info: Linux build10.nj1.10gen                                                                                        .cc 2.6.32-431.3.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jan 3 21:39:27 UTC 2014 x86_64 BOOST_LI                                                                                        B_VERSION=1_49
2015-01-10T10:46:33.109-0500 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2015-01-10T10:46:33.109-0500 [initandlisten] options: { repair: true }
2015-01-10T10:46:33.112-0500 [initandlisten] finished checking dbs
2015-01-10T10:46:33.112-0500 [initandlisten] dbexit:
2015-01-10T10:46:33.112-0500 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening                                                                                         sockets...
2015-01-10T10:46:33.112-0500 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2015-01-10T10:46:33.112-0500 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
2015-01-10T10:46:33.112-0500 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocat                                                                                        or...
2015-01-10T10:46:33.112-0500 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
2015-01-10T10:46:33.112-0500 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
2015-01-10T10:46:33.112-0500 [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
2015-01-10T10:46:33.112-0500 [initandlisten] dbexit: really exiting now
```

Comment: didn't ````mongodb --repair```` work? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884233/mongodb-service-is-not-starting-up

Comment: What language/tool are you using to access the dB?  What kind of error is it giving?

Comment: @ErikVandeVen : Nope try it out it doesnt solves the problem

Comment: @ZacWolf : using PHP also try to access remotely using MongoVue both are showing that remove server refused connection

Comment: It looks like you might have two problems? Can you show how you connect locally and how you try to connect remotely? That problem wouldn't necessarily be related to the service restart not working as expected, especially since we see the mongod running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove this line from mongo's config file (on Ubuntu, mine is at /etc/mongod.conf):

```
bind_ip = 127.0.0.1
```

Or, if it's YAML,

```
bindIp: 127.0.0.1
```

Source: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

"Changed in version 2.6.0: The deb and rpm packages include a default configuration file that sets net.bindIp to 127.0.0.1."

The default value for bindIp/bind_ip is "all interfaces" - so that's where the deletion comes in handy.

Comment: my conf file is showing bind_ip = 0.0.0.0 guess that will allow external access