# Mongodb server not starting up after changing dbpath

Tags: mongodb

I changed dbpath of my mongodb, and moved content of earlier dbpath folder to the new one. But the server is not starting up. Upon investigating mongodb logs, I found following exception:

> 016-05-23T10:50:51.697+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen std::exception: boost::filesystem::status: Permission denied: "/media/user/Shared/mongodb/storage.bson", terminating

I found a similar [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884233/mongodb-service-is-not-starting-up), but it did not help me fix the issue. Here is the current permissions of my **dbpath** folder and **storage.bson** file:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mongodb mongodb         69    May 23 08:57 storage.bson*
drwxrwxrwx 3 mongodb mongodb         4096  May 23 09:04 mongodb/
```

I did try removing lock file (/var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock) but it also did not help me.

BTW, I am using version **v3.0.8** of MongoDB and starting it through
    **sudo service mongodb start**

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem resolved by adding the executable permission to other users on the /home, and all the way down to the db path.   for example:

`chmod -R o+x /<home>`

or more specific (*notice the -R recursive flag*)

`chmod o+x /<home>
chmod -R o+x /<home>/mongodb`

Comment: Solved my problem but I had to make a slight modification to the second command so that it became: `chmod -R o+rwx /<home>/mongodb`

Comment: Had to follow the instructions in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41615574/mongodb-server-has-startup-warnings-access-control-is-not-enabled-for-the-dat) thread to get rid of the warning `WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.`